# Scala's Stack: () versus {}

Tags: scala, scope

I was writing some scala code:

```
def getOpponentOf(request) 
   = if (getPlayerTupleOf(request)._1.id == request.id)
        getPlayerTupleOf(request)._1
     else getPlayerTupleOf(request)._2
```

Now, my imperative mind was going: "Hey, why would I wont define a local variable which references getPlayerTuple once and then use that reference.

But then I would have to use the {} scope as opposed to () (which is more functional?)
Assuming that the function getPlayerTupleOf is perfectly functional too i.e. using () scope, side-effect free etc.

What are the performance/compiler implications when for example executing the above versus this:

```
def getOpponentOf(request) = {
    val playerTuple = getPlayerTupleOf(request)

    if (playerTuple._1.id == request.id)
        playerTuple._1
     else playerTuple._2
}
```

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: In first solution `getPlayerTupleOf(request)` you call three times. And your create tree tuples. In second you call it one time and you return one object. The first solution is three time expensive (memory + time of execution)

Comment: but I thought the whole point about functional paradigms is that references are cheap to get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a block {} does not oppose functional programming. Scala "val" declarations are equivalent to the "let" binding present in other functional languages (e.g. ML, F#), and thus they are perfectly "functional" concepts. What isn't functional is using a *real* variable defined as **var** instead of **val**.

About performance: the compiler usually cannot know for sure that your method is side-effect free and multiple invocations with the same argument can be "cached" (e.g. in the form of a local "variable"). So, the compiled code will effectively call the method as many times as you wrote it. There is still the option for the JIT to effectively optimize it at runtime, and it may or may not happen, depending on how your method is implemented and on other factors.

I think there are also other aspects to consider: conciseness, maintainability, and the second version wins here: there is no code duplication, and the name of the variable can help understanding the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered this approach?

```
def getOpponentOf(request) = getPlayerTupleOf(request) match {
  case (opponent, _) if opponent.id == request.id => opponent
  case (_, opponent) => opponent
}
```

I really have no idea what the items in your tuple represent, and this is why you should try to avoid tuples unless their meaning is inherently clear. Perhaps a named type of some kind would work better here (trying again to guess what your tuple means):

```
case class Players(playerA: Player, playerB: Player)

def getOpponentOf(request) = getPlayersOf(request) match {
  case Players(a, _) if a.id = request.id => a
  case Players(_, b) => b
}
```

This might make sense if you're using the result from `getPlayersOf` in a lot of other places. If not, then maybe the simpler thing to do is put `getOpponent` (or simply `opponent`) on your request object, then all of this becomes:

```
request.opponent
```

You might consider using Stack Exchange's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site to show more of your code and solicit further feedback.